# How to get a data in a text box by the index change of DropDownList in asp.net?

Tags: drop-down-menu, nullreferenceexception, cascading

I am doing this using layer architecture and the code and problem is below. I want to get the course title in the text box by a course code of the DropDownList. The problem is null reference. Please help me to solve this problem. N.B: Course Code and course title placed in the same table.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're passing the course title into the SQL instead of the course code. If you are passing the course code, it may be an idea to rename your parameters to avoid confusion.

How are you building the select list? Are you sure that the value and text are correctly assigned?

Comment: then why it is giving the null exception?